# Rails - Changing the config path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I copied the 'config' directory and renamed it to 'config_dev' so that I don't alter the current settings. How do I configure Rails to use the config directory of 'config_dev'?

Comment: Hold on. Before you do this, why don't you use the development environment to customize your settings there? That's what it's for.

Comment: I want to keep everything in the 'config' folder just as it is so I don't change anything from the live server. Please tell me how to set it to use 'config_dev' and I can just set it back once I'm done.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i'm not sure whether you can rename that and still make it work or not. However, i would highly not recommend that approach. If you must do something like that, better rename the files inside the folder, like environment.rb.bak or the likes.

Generally speaking a config folder is where important settings initiate from and i think that changing that convention can lead to more problems. I could be wrong, but i would just change the files (that's what the rails 2 to rails 3 conversion plugin does as well).